# Prove $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb T) \quad ||f*g||_{\infty}\le ||f||_{p}||g||_{q} , \quad \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

Tags: real-analysis

I've proof this in the $L^p(R^n)$ spaces.The proof is similar in $L^1(\mathbb T)$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{T}$? What did you try?

Comment: $\mathbb T is \{ z\in \mathbb C: |z|=1 \}$ so f and g are $2\pi $ periodic functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard exercise in any real-analysis course (or Fourier analysis course). Although, I do not know what you mean by you have a proof in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n).$ I understand there is a statement like this, but there is one subtle difference here. Here your assumption is that $f, g\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ which in turn implies that $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{T})$ and $g\in L^q(\mathbb{T})$ for any $p, q.$ This is true because $\mathbb{T}$ has a finite measure. In $\mathbb{R}^n,$ one needs to start with the assumption that $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n).$

But except this small caveat, you are right. If you know the proof for $\mathbb{R}^n,$ the same argument will give you the proof for $\mathbb{T}.$
For the sake of completeness, I briefly sketch the proof below.

$$|f*g(\theta)|\le\int |f(\phi)g(\theta-\phi)d\phi|\le \left(\int |f(\phi)|^pd\phi\right)^{1/p}\left(\int |g(\theta-\phi)|^qd\phi\right)^{1/q}.$$

The last inequality is, of course, Hölder's inequality. (I take $d\phi$ to be normalized measure, otherwise there will be a factor of $2\pi$). Lastly, one just have to observe that $\int |g(\theta-\phi)|^qd\phi= \int |g(\phi)|^qd\phi,$ which follows by a simple change of variable (or more generally by observing that $d\phi$ is the Haar measure on $\mathbb{T}$).

Since the right-hand side of the above inequality is independent of theta, one concludes that $||f*g||_{\infty}\le ||f||_p||g||_q.$

Comment: I fixed a typo, I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Reveillark Thanks! I was writing while watching a movie. :)